# Elasticsearch query is flushing all data instead of terms only search with python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I need to query all values from a certain field in my elastic index.
When I search for terms in the elasticsearch dev console, I get the results as expected:

```
GET index/_search
{
    "aggs" : {
        "All_IDs" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "ID", "size":10000 }
        }
    },
    "size" : 0
}
```

response:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "All_IDs" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "XX05215",
          "doc_count" : 4560
        },
        {
          "key" : "XX05216",
          "doc_count" : 3364
        },
        {
          "key" : "E1004903",
          "doc_count" : 2369
        }....
```

That's good!
But, when I use the elasticsearch client in python, the response contains the aggregation, but I also get flushed with the data from the entire database, which is too much overhead:

```
es = Elasticsearch(
    hosts = [{'host': host, 'port': 443},],
    http_auth = awsauth,
    use_ssl = True,
    verify_certs = True,
    connection_class = RequestsHttpConnection
)


query = {
    
        "aggs" : {
            "All_IDs" : {
                "terms" : { "field" : "ID", "size":10000 }
            }
        },
        "size" : 0
    }

response = es.search( index='index', body=query, size=9999 )
```

How can I query in python the same way as in the console and retrieve only the desired ID's?

Comment: can you remove `size=9999` from your `es.search( index='index', body=query, size=9999 )` and see the result?

Comment: Agreed with @Amit, doesn't make sense to have size=9999 there

Comment: I removed the size setting and now it works! great. Thank you! Do you want to post an answer?

Comment: @stanvooz great, posted answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was with the `size` param passed in the query request as shown in below request.

```
es.search( index='index', body=query, size=9999 )
```

Once its removed, it used the `size` param passed in the query body.